# Unity app crashes when built for iOS with camera enabled

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, ios-permissions

I have an app which uses zxing to scan qr codes in the app. However when I build the app with these scripts in the scene the app crashes on startup. I thought it was something in the Awake() or Start() but I've wrapped those methods in a try catch, and even then I'm not getting any errors, and it doesn't crash on android and in the editor.

I don't have access to a Mac, and am using Unity Cloud Build to build it.

I also don't know how to enable permissions, I thought I did when creating the .p12 file, but I've also found that there's an info.plist file that I have to request permissions with.

Prior research I found this [Unity Question about adding items to the Xcode project](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-can-you-add-items-to-the-xcode-project-targets-info-plist-using-the-xcodeapi.330574/) but not only did including the xcodeapi give me errors, but the using statements didn't work.

There are two scripts

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class WebCamController : MonoBehaviour {

    public int desiredWidth = 1280;
    public int desiredHeight = 720;
    public int desiredFPS = 60;
    public RawImage output;
    [HideInInspector]
    public WebCamTexture webcamTexture;

    void Start ()
    {
        webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture(desiredWidth, desiredHeight, desiredFPS);
        output.texture = webcamTexture;
        Play();
    }
    public void Play()
    {
        webcamTexture.Play();
    }
    public void Pause()
    {
        webcamTexture.Stop();
    }

}
```

and

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

using ZXing;
using ZXing.QrCode;
using ZXing.Common;
using System;

public class CodeScanner : MonoBehaviour {
    private static CodeScanner _instance;
    public static CodeScanner Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(null == _instance)
            {
                Debug.Log("Code Scanner Instance not found");
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    [Header("References")]
    public WebCamController wcc;

    [Header("Properties")]
    private BarcodeReader codeScanner;
    private string lastScanned = "";

    public delegate void Found(string text, string type);
    public event Found OnCodeScanned;
    private bool active;

    public void Awake()
    {
        _instance = this;
    }

    void Start () {
        codeScanner = new BarcodeReader();
        StartCoroutine(ReadCode());
        wcc.Play();
    }

    IEnumerator ReadCode()
    {
        while (active)
        {
            try
            {
                var data = codeScanner.Decode(wcc.webcamTexture.GetPixels32(), wcc.webcamTexture.width, wcc.webcamTexture.height);
                if (data != null)
                {
                    //if (data.Text != lastScanned)
                    //{
                    OnCodeScanned(data.Text, data.BarcodeFormat.ToString());
                    //}
                    lastScanned = data.Text;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        }
    }


    public void Activate()
    {
        wcc.Play();
        active = true;
        StartCoroutine(ReadCode());
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        active = false;
        wcc.Pause();
    }
}
```

My device is added properly to the .p12 certificate I can compile and run the program without these scripts in the scene.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: updated with scripts in scene